# can we make column of celltable flow horizontally rather than vertically?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

ok, here is my problem, cos the space is limited, i want to make my celltable (has 1 column naming Page) flows horizontally.

Traditionally a 1 column celltable look like this:

```
Page
1
2
3
....
```

I want to make it looks like this.

```
Page 1 2 3 ......
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use celltable, but custome CellList, that will be fine

```
public class HorizontalCellList<T> extends CellList<T> {

  public HorizontalCellList(Cell<T> cell) {
    super(cell);
  }

  @Override
  protected void renderRowValues(
      SafeHtmlBuilder sb, List<T> values, int start, SelectionModel<? super T> selectionModel) {
    SafeHtmlBuilder filteredSB = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    super.renderRowValues(filteredSB, values, start, selectionModel);
    SafeHtml safeHtml = filteredSB.toSafeHtml();
    String filtered = safeHtml.asString().replaceAll("<div", "<span").replaceAll("div>","span>");
    sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(filtered));
  }
}
```

Comment: The string replacement is a slightly terrifying way to change to inline elements - consider instead using CSS that tweaks those particular div elements (by their class, likely as not) to be `display:inline` or `float:left` instead of rewriting the *html* with a *regex*.

Comment: have you test ur code? i tried {.horizontalCellList {
    display: inline; } but it is not working? can you provide your code?

Comment: Don't apply it to the whole cell list - apply it to the cells themselves. For the CellList to work with it, you will need to build a clientbundle that extends the CellList's own clientbundle, and add more css to it (probably on the `.cellListEvenItem` and `.cellListOddItem` styles, since no other style is added to the items themselves).